# Hash join performance origin

Tags: database, postgresql, join, hash

Wikipedia says:

> First prepare a hash table of the smaller relation. The hash table
>   entries consist of the join attribute and its row. Because the hash
>   table is accessed by applying a hash function to the join attribute,
>   it will be much quicker to find a given join attribute's rows by using
>   this table than by scanning the original relation.

It appears as if speed of this join algorithm is due to that we hash R(lesser sized relation) but not S(other, larger one).

My question is how do we compare hashed versions of R's rows to S without running the hash function on S as well? Do we presume DB stores one for us? 
Or am I wrongly assuming about not hashing S, and speed advantage is due to comparing hashes(unique, small) as opposed to reading through actual data of the rows(not unique, might be large)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash function will also be used on the join attribute in *S*.

I think that the meaning of the quoted paragraph is that applying the hash function on the attribute, finding the correct hash bucket and following the linked list will be faster than searching for the corresponding row of the table *R* with a table or index scan.

The trade-off for this speed gain is the cost of building the hash.